# Image BackgroundColor platform specific from xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have `Image` control in xaml, how can I give `BackgroundColor` only for **`iOS`** from xaml only

```
<Image BackgroundColor="Green" Source="bell.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" >
</Image>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add inline code in xaml

```
<Image  BackgroundColor="{ x:OnPlatform iOS='Green', Default='White'}">
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your resource dictionary, add this:

```xml
<OnPlatform x:Key="MyBackgroundColor" x:TypeArguments="Color">
    <On Platform="iOS">Green</On>
    <On Platform="Android">Transparent</On>
    <On Platform="Windows">Transparent</On>
</OnPlatform>
```

Then, use the resource in your image:

```xml
<Image
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MyBackgroundColor}"
    ... />
```